# Making asynchronous functions in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have 4 functions that I wrote in python. I want to make first 3 functions asynchronous.
So it should look like this:

```
x = 3.13
def one(x):
   return x**x

def two(x):
   return x*x*12-314

def three(x):
   return x+x+352+x**x


def final(x):

   one = one(x)
   two = two(x)
   three = three(x)

   return one, two, three
```

This is what I did:

```
async def one(x):
   return x**x

async def two(x):
   return x*x*12-314

async def three(x):
   return x+x+352+x**x


def final(x):

   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

   one = loop.create_task(one(x))
   two = loop.create_task(two(x))
   three = loop.create_task(three(x))


   #loop.run_until_complete('what should be here')
   #loop.close()

   return one, two, three
```

But I get this error (if lines above are not commented):

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I do not know what is wrong (Im new to this), I have also tried to add this:

```
await asyncio.wait([one,two,three])
```

but to be honest I do not know where and why should I add it.
Without that, my code works but it does not give me result, it prints this:

```
(<Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<one() running at /Users/.../Desktop/....py:63>>, <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<two() running at /Users/.../Desktop/...py:10>>, <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<three() running at /Users/.../Desktop/...py:91>>)
```

Any help?

Comment: Why are you calling final inside final?

Comment: whoa, thats my error, but what should I call? I will delete that line

Comment: Are you aware that making these functions "asynchronous" by declaring them ``async`` has no benefit at all? If you are just experimenting to see how to write asynchronous code, following a tutorial might be better than trial-and-error on a self-written toy example.

Comment: I want to combine these 3 functions in one, but I want to make them asynchronous. I have watched tutorials, but for some reason it does not work like I expected.
If you can, please explain me how to fix my problem

Comment: you need also a sort of long task like io or sleep to demonstrate the async activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major purpose of `async` syntax and its libraries is to hide the details of event loops. Prefer to use high-level APIs directly:

```py
def final(x):
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   return loop.run_until_complete(  # run_until_complete fetches the task results
       asyncio.gather(one(x), two(x), three(x))  # gather runs multiple tasks
   )

print(final(x))  # [35.5675357348548, -196.43720000000002, 393.8275357348548]
```

---

If you want to explicitly control concurrency, i.e. when functions are launched as tasks, it is simpler to do this inside another `async` function. In your example, making `final` an `async` function simplifies things by giving direct access to `await` and the ambient loop:

```py
async def final(x):  # async def – we can use await inside
   # create task in whatever loop this function runs in
   task_one = asyncio.create_task(one(x))
   task_two = asyncio.create_task(two(x))
   task_three = asyncio.create_task(three(x))
   # wait for completion and fetch result of each task
   return await task_one, await task_two, await task_three

print(asyncio.run(final(x)))  # (35.5675357348548, -196.43720000000002, 393.8275357348548)
```

Comment: And should I have loop.close() anywhere?
I have seen in some tutorials that they are putting that

Comment: I recommend not to explicitly close a loop unless you have to (i.e. you get errors of pending tasks). The purpose of closing a loop is to cancel any tasks that are still queued;  ideally, you should not have any queued tasks by the time the loop has done your work. Cargo-culting explicit closing of the loop can accidentally silence errors from tasks that *should* have finished by themselves but did not.

Comment: And what should I do if I get this kind of error: raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Comment: @taga If this is specifically related to this question/answer, please provide the full traceback. If this is about a new problem/setup, please look for existing questions/answers and consider to ask a new question. I am afraid it is impossible to tell from just that error message.

Comment: Its about same question, I get that error in this line : loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(one(x), two(x), three(x))

Comment: Please make sure you are using the correct, ``async`` definitions of all functions. Check the type of each function, e.g. ``type(one)`` and ``type(one(x))`` should be ``function`` and ``coroutine`` (ignore the ``RuntimeWarning`` if one occurs).